# choose function by select in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I have 2 selects and one button with function. I want to check if the location is selected then do location part of code, if assigned selected then do assigned part of code. it works if both are null in api ;), then i can change one of them.

```
$scope.edit_location = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++) {
        if($scope.currentInventory.location){

            console.log('I am in location');
            var copySelectedInv = Restangular.copy($scope.currentInventory);
            copySelectedInv.customPUT({location: $scope.currentInventory.location, assigned: null,  tags: $scope.inventories[i].tags}); 

        }else if ($scope.currentInventory.assigned){

            console.log('I am in assigned');
            var copySelectedInv2 = Restangular.copy($scope.currentInventory);
            copySelectedInv2.customPUT({location: null, assigned: $scope.currentInventory.assigned,  tags: $scope.inventories[i].tags});    
        }
    }
};
```

my template selects

```
 <select class="input-medium form-control" ng-model="currentInventory.location">
        <option value="">Choose location</option>
        <option value="{{location.resource_uri}}" ng-repeat="location in locations">{{location.name}}</option>  
</select>
<h5>Assigne to employee</h5>
 <select class="input-medium form-control" ng-model="currentInventory.assigned">
        <option value="">Choose location</option>
        <option value="{{user.resource_uri}}" ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name}}</option> 
</select>

<button class="btn tbn-lg btn-success" ng-click="edit_location()">
```

Comment: you need the 2 selected values to be mutually exclusive, right? Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ng-options` instead:

```
<select class="input-medium form-control" ng-model="currentInventory.location" 
        ng-options="location.resource_uri as location.name for location in locations">
        <option value="">Choose location</option> 
</select>
```

If you need that selecting a value will deselect the other, a quick solution is:

```
$scope.$watch("currentInventory.assigned",function(newValue,oldValue,scope){
    scope.currentInventory.location = null;
});

$scope.$watch("currentInventory.location",function(newValue,oldValue,scope){
    scope.currentInventory.assigned = null;
});
```

Another solution is binding with `object` as value instead of just `resource_uri` property:

```
<select class="input-medium form-control" ng-model="currentInventory" 
            ng-options="location.name for location in locations">
            <option value="">Choose location</option> 
</select>
```

And check whether it's a location or a user:

```
$scope.edit_location = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++) {
        if($scope.locations.indexOf($scope.currentInventory)>=0){

            console.log('I am in location');
            var copySelectedInv = Restangular.copy($scope.currentInventory);
            copySelectedInv.customPUT({location: $scope.currentInventory.location, assigned: null,  tags: $scope.inventories[i].tags}); 

        }else if ($scope.users.indexOf($scope.currentInventory)>=0){

            console.log('I am in assigned');
            var copySelectedInv2 = Restangular.copy($scope.currentInventory);
            copySelectedInv2.customPUT({location: null, assigned: $scope.currentInventory.assigned,  tags: $scope.inventories[i].tags});    
        }
    }
};
```